# Couchbase XDCR not replicating data for larger number of replications

Tags: couchbase

I'm using the XDCR REST API to create bi-directional replications between the buckets of two clusters running versions 4.1.0-5005 and 4.5.0-1308 (8 buckets on each cluster, 8*2 replications). The maximum number of records to be synced between any two buckets is ~20k. The replication isn't progressing at all, there is no change in the buckets of either cluster even after an hour.

However when I create a replication between two buckets and add a record to one of the buckets it gets replicated instantly, so I assume the issue isn't with the replications created. Is there any hard limit on the number of replications that can be created between two clusters or any other reason this might be happening?

**EDIT**

The issue was with running different versions of couchbase servers on the clusters. The issue got resolved when the same version was used on both servers.